# How to connect/telnet to SPOP3 server using java (Sockets)?

Tags: java, sockets, openssl, telnet, pop3

In case of POP3 it is possible to connect via telnet using sockets over port 110, But how to do it , if SPOP3 is implemented.
With normal telnet it can be done quite easily with

```
Socket pop3Socket = new Socket(host.com, 110);
```

FYI:
For connecting to SPOP3 we use in linux/unix

```
 openssl s_client -connect servername.com:995
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the SSLSocket class.   An example can be found at:  http://www.herongyang.com/JDK/SSL-Socket-Client-Example-SslSocketClient.html.

Basically, you'll do something like:

```
SSLSocketFactory f = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket c =        (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("localhost", 8888);
```

If the endpoint has a self signed certificate then you have two options:

1. Add this self-signed cert to your local keystore.  This URL gives a good overview:  http://www.chrissearle.org/blog/technical/adding_self_signed_https_certificates_java_keystore
2. Create a TrustManager that does not validate the server's certificate:  http://www.howardism.org/Technical/Java/SelfSignedCerts.html

Option 1 is more secure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But How do i accept self signed certificate. As  we are testing with self generated certificate. Any way out ?